# How can I create multiple rows based on the value of one column in SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column of type string in my table, where multiple values are separated by pipe operator. For example, like this,

```
Value1|Value2|Value3
```

Now, what I want is to have a query, which will show three rows for this row. Basically something similar to the concept of explode in Dataframes.

Note that I am using Spark SQL. And I want to achieve this using SQL, not dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the following query.

```
select t.*, explode(split(values, "\\|")) as value
from table t
```

`\\|` here can also be replaced by `[|]`. Just specifying `|` doesn't work.